# Apache wildcard domains - Restrict number of subdomain levels

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I would like to setup a VirtualHost which allows for wildcard subdomains such as `foo.sites.example.com` and `bar.sites.example.com`.  I do not, however, wish to allow multiple level subdomains such as `foo.bar.sites.example.com`.  The following meets the first requirement but not the second.  It could be accomplished with mod_rewrite, however, I expect there is a simpler way.  I am using Apache 2.2 but could upgrade if necessary.  How is this accomplished?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sites.example.com
    ServerAlias *.sites.example.com
    # ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict the use of `foo.bar.sites.example.com` you have to place another VirtualHost above the existing one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.bar.sites.example.com
    ServerAlias *.*.sites.example.com
    # ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you can block or redirect the access. However it's important that you place it **above** the other VirtualHost since Apache always takes the first VirtualHost when multiple entries match.

Comment: I don't think we can use wildcard with `ServerName`.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar Thanks for pointing out, I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Send all request `(ServerAlias *.*.example.com)` to a php file.
And redirect where you want :

```
$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$subdomains=explode('.', $url);

$subdomains[0] : first subdomain
$subdomains[0] : second subdomain ...
```

You can redirect with

```
header('Location: '.$URL);
```